# How can I avoid repeated network requests with Picasso for resized images?

Tags: android, image, android-lifecycle, picasso

When I use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) in different activities and monitor network requests, what I see is that the first activity creates a network request for image A. Before image A is loaded the user may tap somewhere and open a second activity which also loads image A. Now I see a second network request has been opened to fetch A **again**, which means downloading twice the same image.

Is there any way to tell Picasso to instead wait for the first request to complete and reuse its results to avoid consuming bandwidth?

**UPDATE**: After testing a bit more I found out that the problem doesn't have anything to do with separate activities. I created a test from scratch where two different activities loaded an image and a single request was done for both, which is wonderful. The behaviour in my production app however keeps happening, and is likely due to images being resized and cropped to different sizes. In one activity the user image is displayed as a cropped miniature circle, on another it is shown without resizing. Here is an example which reproduces the problem:

```
    String IMAGE_URL = "http://www.elhaso.es/temp/big.jpg";
    Picasso.with(this)
            .load(IMAGE_URL)
            .into(mImage1);
    Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
            .load(IMAGE_URL)
            .resize(233, 333).centerCrop()
            .into(mImage2);
```

This code will open and download the image url twice despite being the same resource because of the `.resize(233, 333).centerCrop()` line. If this line is removed, Picasso will do a single request and share the result among images. Since the behaviour without resizing is good, is this maybe a bug? For the record this happens using 2.5.0.

Comment: Hi @GrzegorzAdamHankiewicz, did you find the cause of the issue?

Answer (score 4):

To pause and resume requests with `Picasso`, first add a tag:

```
Picasso.with(context)
   .load("http://example.com/image.jpg")
   .tag(someTag)
   .into(someImageView)
```

and then call

```
picasso.resumeTag(someTag);
```

or

```
picasso.pauseTag(someTag);
```

Similarly, to cancel requests, use

```
picasso.cancelRequest();
```

So along these lines, you need to call `pauseTag()` and `resumeTag()` in the `onPause()` and `onResume()` methods of the `Activity` & `Fragment` classes, and similarly `cancelRequest()` in `onStop()` and `onDestroy()`.

For reference see [here](https://github.com/square/picasso/tree/master/picasso-sample/src/main/java/com/example/picasso). Do keep in mind that you need the new jar [(v2.5.0)](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/squareup/picasso/picasso/2.5.0/picasso-2.5.0.jar) to do all this.

The "false answer" that [Jake Wharton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/132047/jake-wharton) castigated below was this:

> `Picasso` doesn't play well with the `Activity` / `Fragment`
>   lifecycles.
>   [`Volley`](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html)
>   does. You can cancel an ongoing request from `onPause()` or
>   `onDestroy()` or `onStop()`. You can even cancel all ongoing requests
>   in one shot (messy, but it works).
>
> So the short answer to your question is NO, because `Picasso` can't
>   help you out with with the `Activity` / `Fragment` lifecycles.

Comment: So, yeah, this is entirely false. First, Picasso has all the same control for pausing, resuming, and canceling. Second, canceling in Picasso and Volley doesn't actually cancel the underlying network request if it has already started. You'll see the same behavior form both.

Comment: I have just taken a look at the library again, and you're right, so I apologize for this. I *have* done these things with `Volley` but not with `Picasso`. I will avoid giving answers based on hearsay from now on :)

Comment: We were ashamed of seeing answers like yours which used to be true. So we added those features!

Comment: @GrzegorzAdamHankiewicz: was this useful ?

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I already knew about pausing/resuming but further investigation shows this is not the problem after trying to reduce the bug to a smaller example. I've updated the question with further details.